# 2 ceiling lights into 2 switches? Or not...?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

**PS there's more images in the comments as I couldn't post them all in the post!

Right so we've recently moved house and we're having a few issues in one of the living rooms....
There are 2 ceiling chandelier type lights in the room with the one 2 gang switch however when there are 3 bulbs in each fitting they are extremely dim... however with 2 bulbs in the first light (closest to the switch) if you take a bulb out then the other 2 get brighter, and the other fitting getting dimmer and vice versa when you do it the other way around.

If you have one bulb in the farthest fitting then the other fitting has only got a faint glow.... 
if you have no bulbs in the first fitting then the second one doesn't work, but there is still still mains power in the negative and positive wires when I checked with a mains tester screwdriver. When doing the Same on the first fitting only the live from the switch shows on the screwdriver
[image]

Another issue is that one of the switches on the 2 gang doesn't seem to do anything and only one switch puts on both chandeliers

[image]

This is the wiring going into the first fitting closet to the plug. The grey to blue is the live that is in the switch

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UdltL.jpg this is the second fitting

Comment: [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnmko.jpg this is the fittings with all the bulbs in them

Comment: [5]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NQSUa.jpg when I remove a bulb from the first fitting

Comment: [6]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2R4ba.jpg and this is when I take a bulb out of the farthest fitting